# TF quaternion rotation problem

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to rotate a quaternion by a yaw angle.
q1 is the quaternion that I want to rotate

```
q1 = quaternion_from_euler(math.pi/2, math.pi/4, math.pi/4)
```

I want to rotate q1 by 1/4 pi yaw so I create another quaternion q2 for the purpose

```
q2 = quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, math.pi/4)
```

I then rotate q1 and I expect the result to be (pi/2, pi/4, pi/2) roll-pitch-yaw

```
q3 = quaternion_multiply(q1, q2)
```

But when I convert the result to Euler below is the value.

```
e3 = euler_from_quaternion(q3)
print e3
(1.5707963267948966, -0.0, 0.7853981633974484)
```

Looks like it rotates pitch by -pi/4 instead of the yaw by pi/4.
Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277035/tf-quaternion-rotation-problem/) by [jlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30223/jlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `q3 = quaternion_multiply(q2, q1)`. Order matters.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30223/jlin/) on 2017-12-01**:
Thanks. That works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on Andy's answer, the order determines whether you're applying a global or local rotation.

```
q3 = quaternion_multiply(q1, q2)
```

Here q3 is the **local rotation** of **q2 on q1**
or
the **global rotation** of **q1 on q2**

---

```
q3 = quaternion_multiply(q2, q1)
```

Here q3 is the **local rotation** of **q1 on q2**
or
the **global rotation** of **q2 on q1**

---

In your case, you wanted to apply a **global rotation of q2 on q1** -
*i.e. apply the rotation q2 according to q1's parent coordinate frame (the coordinate frame on which q1 was applied initially)*

---

Further reading / maths:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/810579/quaternion-multiplication-order.html#
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124361/quaternions-multiplication-order-to-rotate-unrotate/2125858#2125858

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30223/jlin/) on 2017-12-01**:
Thanks! That really helps.